# Change the text font of Eclipse into Courier New

Tags: eclipse, fonts

I already know how to change the text font of Eclipse. But I can't find the font style "Courier New". Does there anyone know how to manage it?

My Eclipse version is:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Indigo Service Release 1

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the tip:

You can find

> C:\Windows\Fonts  -> Courier New

*Click right and choose* **"Show"**